# Can I pass a variable in a template binding?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-templating

I know this isn't a good method to use long term, but for troubleshooting, is there any way I can pass a simple string while binding a template and then access it as a variable within the template?  For instance, if this was my binding:

```
<!-- ko template: { name: tmplOne }, myvar: 'apple' -->
```

and this was **tmplOne**:

```
<div>
    <span>Fruit: </span>
    <span data-bind="text: myvar"></span>
</div>
```

It would result in the folowing:

```
fruit: apple
```

Even if I have to declare an observable in the viewmodel called "fruit", can I manually set it at template binding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
<!-- ko template: { name: tmplOne, templateOptions: {myvar: 'apple'} } -->
```

More here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/03/quick-tip-reusing-template-by-passing.html

Comment: How is this different than the accepted answer?  What is the difference between/advantages of `templateOptions` vs `data`?

Comment: I think this is the correct approach for this problem, don't know why it's downvoted.

Comment: @DevilsAdvocate The underlying viewmodel and a render-time template parameter are two different things. The accepted answer messes with the viewmodel and introduces a new binding context while you asked for a simple render-time parameter, keeping the binding context tree untouched (if I understood correctly)..

Comment: Unfortunately `templateOptions` is no longer supported

Answer (score 5):

You can supply a data parameter to the template binding and define an object literal if you want just like you are doing:

```
<!-- ko template: { name: tmplOne }, myvar: 'apple' -->
```

instead do this:

```
<!-- ko template: { name: tmplOne, data: { myvar: 'apple' } } -->
```

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html

Comment: and then I access it using "myvar" just as I did in my example?

Comment: Wait, reading the docs you just linked, does this mean if I include the data object it will overwrite the currently applied viewmodel?

Comment: You'll be accessing the $parent or $root objects in order to get the 'myvar' object.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding.  Now all my existing bindings don't work.  How can I pass the existing object AND specify the custom variable? eg, data: { $data, myvar: 'apple' }

Comment: I figured you were defining the viewmodel on your template page already. In which case you'd use the model as normal and access 'myvar' as previously shown. If that doesn't work, you can also try adding a 'myvar' to your viewmodel object on your template page (and then access it as normal). A last try would be just passing your object with the other variable as you just suggested, but I don't think that should be necessary. data: { mydata: mydataobject, myvar: 'apple' }

Comment: I obviously am fairly new to KO and templating both, so I appreciate your patience and help.  I have a POC coming up soon which is why I'm trying to hack it for now :\, ultimately I'll figure out a way to do it right :)

Comment: You technically answered my question, and I have made progress, so I went ahead and accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

For people reading on later versions of knockout, this would appear to be a good usecase for components vs templates.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arbitrary data to a template, while maintaining the currently applied viemodel, by supplying a composition to the `data` parameter of the binding.

You could for example wrap the template content in a `with` binding, bound to the composed `$data` property, creating a new binding context. This way, the currently applied bindings don't need to be updated.

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  fruits: ['banana', 'orange']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'tmplOne', data: { myModelData: $data, myVar: 'apple' } }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="tmplOne">
  <!-- ko with: myModelData -->
    <span>My model</span>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: fruits">
      <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
      <span>My custom data:</span>
      <span data-bind="text: $parent.myVar"></span>
    </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```